# Other non-image related code before and after header no longer work

Tags: php, header, gd, jpeg

I am trying to use  header('Content-type: image/jpeg') to edit and display jpeg photos as follows.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg') 
$filename = 'aaa.jpg';
 $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST,50);
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

In the same file,I also have other simple codes like $abc = $_POST['abc']. 
After I put the header, code before the header and code after image destroy($im) no longer work. And when I put any code such as $_post['abc'] before the header, both header and code doesn't work. All codes were fine before I included header and code to manipulate and output image. It is my first time using header('Content-type: image/jpeg') and I cannot find the answer after trying for so long. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to output html page, do not send image header. But instead, at first output the transformed image to a file on your server and add the `<img>` or `<a>`nchor tag in your html page:

```php
<html><body>
<?php
$output_dir = 'images';
if (!file_exists($output_dir)) {
    mkdir($output_dir, 0777);
}
$filename = 'aaa.jpg';
$filename2 = 'aaa2.jpg';
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    echo 'Input image not exists!'; exit;
}
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, 50);
imagejpeg($im, $output_dir.'/'.$filename2);
imagedestroy($im);

echo 'Original image:<br/><img src="'.$filename.'" /><br/>';
echo 'Transformed image:<br/><img src="'.$output_dir.'/'.$filename2.'" />';
?>
</body></html>
```

That image header send in case, you want to output it as standalone image. For more examples have a look at [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php#refsect1-function.imagejpeg-examples).